# Azure, Microsoft Bot Framework error: Application with identifier **** was not found

Tags: azure, skype-bots

Just happened with my skype bot: nlsql

Nothing was committed or changed, in one moment I got an error:

```
Application with identifier **** was not found in the directory botframework.com\r\nTrace ID
```

Probably some new Azure changes for bot framework? new link for connect?

No errors on Microsoft Azure.

Comment: I got exact same issue. I looked at MS guide and did not see Application Settings for my bot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-overview

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your comment, i didn't know it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it is fine! Seems to be a temporary problem with https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList

error from Microsoft side here was:

```
One or more objects referenced by the access token were not found. Request ID: ff69e3aa-6126-48bd-a118-784eb0d2dae7, Timestamp: 04/06/2018 10:12:08
```

Comment: I have the same issue, in my case App Id and password is provided by my organization admin. How to fix this this, I got error as `unathorised_client`. The admin says botframework.com is not the directory he registered the application.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was re-using an Azure App that was set for a single tenant. So I changed it to Multitenant and it worked.

[image]